# search.in function not return correct results

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am submitting a basic query to my index and then using data from the returned results to further filter that result set using the `$filter` parameter and the `search.in` function. However, when I apply the filter, it subsequently returns 0 results when I would expect it to return a subset of the original result set. I am able to reproduce this issue using the Search Explorer tool in the Azure Search portal.

My initial query is:

```
search=ski
```

... my subsequent filter is ...

```
search=ski&$filter=search.in(categories,'Ski Resorts','|')
```

Initial query returns a bunch of results, many of which have `Ski Resorts` in the categories field. The second query returns no results.

In the index definition, the categories field is defined as an Edm.String field and searchable, filterable, retrievable and facetable. It contains a comma-separated list of categories for the document. My goal is to leverage these categories to allow users to further filter the result set.

Anyone know if I am using the search.in parameter incorrectly? I am going to experiment with other methods for achieving my outcome but curious what might not be right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not surprisingly it was operator error but I definitely learned a good bit.

First, my goal is to allow users to filter down to categories they want. My index field could contain multiple values and I was originally trying to implement it with:

```
$filter=search.in(categories,pipeDelimitedTags,'|')
```

where the `categories` field contains a comma-delimited list of category tags.

However, that expression assumes there is only a single value in the `categories` field.

I updated my index and added a string collection and updated my query expression to:

```
$filter=categoriesCollection/any(c: search.in(c,pipeDelimitedTags,'|'))
```

Now my filter expression appears to be working!

In summary, two key changes:

1. Copy my comma-delimited string into a `Collection(Edm.String)`
2. Use the OData Collection `any` operator with the `search.in` function

For reference, [OData Collection operators in Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-collection-operators)

Thank you for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

I set up an index with the hotels sample data set to test this. In that data set there is an equivalent example with a searchable property, *Category*, that contains 'Suite'. Similarly, the word 'suite' appears in the searchable *Description* property.

My first example yields 20 hits, including an entry where Category is set to 'Suite'.

```
search=suite
```

Then I add the search.in. Unexpectedly, I get 0 hits.

```
search=suite&$filter=search.in(Category, 'suite', '|')
```

After some experimenting I try to switch to uppercase 'Suite', and I get 1 hit.

```
search=suite&$filter=search.in(Category, 'Suite', '|')
```

So, it appears to be a case-sensitivity issue. Surprisingly, many of the built-in analyzers are defined without lowercase. Ask me how I know...

Comment: Filterable fields don't undergo analysis; That's the fundamental difference between search and $filter. $filter expressions, including search.in, are always looking for exact matches (except for search.ismatch/ismatchscoring).